# How to introduce two arguments

Tags: expressions

How to introduce two arguments in a scientific paper?

I used:

```
There are two arguments. On the one hand ARGUMENT1. On the other hand ARGUMENT2.
```

Now I was told I should not use this construct unless I am introducing two contradictory arguments. 
I was told to rather use:

```
There are two arguments. First ARGUMENT1. Second ARGUMENT2.
```

However I actually don't like the second way. Is there any other construct that suits better?

Note: I am not a native speaker therefore I missing some expressions. Probably there is an obvious answer.

Comment: "In the first place...", "in the second place..." might serve your purpose.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, that's better than just using first and second :)

Comment: Firstly, secondly, thirdly, fourthly,...hundredthly,...finally

Comment: @mjsqu Do people really use Firstly? That sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, it is used, but a quick Google search shows that I might be wrong! It is a word, but frowned upon by some.

Comment: *“Argument #1, may I please present to you Argument #2.  Argument #2, this is Argument #1.”*

Comment: @Robin Firstly, I do. And secondly, I'm sure others do!

Comment: I had a friend who habitually said “First of all, *blah blah blah; **second of all,** blah blah blah* …”  I couldn’t convince him that “second of all” was not idiomatic. (This was before [Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=first+of+all%2Csecond+of+all&year_start=1680 "Google Ngram Viewer") even existed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply say:

> [There are two arguments.](http://www.hks.harvard.edu/fs/mrisse/Papers/Current%20Research/IntroducingPluralistInternationalismWZBJuly2013.pdf) One is.... The other is...

Comment: I like that. Easy but effictive.

Answer (score 2):

You may start with:

*The arguments we  present in this paper are two. The first one is about...; the second one deals with.. ..*

Comment: I thought it would be not recommend to use future in a scientific paper?
However, this is nice :)

Comment: I used something like: Throughout the paper we present to arguments.

As I was told not to use future as well as present progressive. This is due to the fact that at the moment somebody reads the paper the paper is already written. Therefore I am not presenting.

Is that wrong?

Comment: "The arguments we present are two" sounds a bit contrived to me (like you are going to make it into a rhyming couplet or something). Why not just "We present two arguments in this paper."

Comment: And, if anyone else is confused by the "future tense" comment, it has been edited out of the answer!

Comment: Some prefer the passive voice in academic writing, so: "*Two arguments are presented in this paper. The first is ...*"